# Strange behavior from input field

Tags: html, css

I have made a form, and now it behaves strangely after a while. I have added neither Javascript nor anything else to it. Here is the link of the form:

http://iranamoozeshgah.com/registration.php?type=p

PROBLEM: clicking on the input fields causes the cursors to focus on the third field, whcih isn't strange??? it is.

This strange problem happpens only in Firefox. My FF version is 24

Comment: Works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox....it is OK in Chrome let me edit the question

Comment: Seems that you are nesting labels in a weird way. Try correcting that. Close your labels in line 220 and 222 and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a `<label>` wrapping inputs 3, 4 and 5, which will cause whenever you click those inputs, the first one in the `<label>` to be selected.